# Disable button on form submit, without preventing HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

Hoping people can help as I'm pulling out my hair. I need to disable the button after clicked because some of my lovely users love spam-clicking the buttons:

[image]

At the moment, if they try to submit without completing a field, the form displays the HTML5 validation errors (both fields are required). However anything I've implemented, onclick, onsubmit, everything that uses JS to disable the button means that the HTML validation no longer runs. I've tried it on the form and on the button, using on event function calls, and with event listeners. I'm stumped.

I know I can complete validation with JS, but I don't really want to have to if I can use HTML5; what would be the point duplicating existing functionality...? Is this possible, or do I need to add the validation from a JS perspective?

After a little while I'm then wanting to un-disable the button to give them chance to respond to the validation errors (if applicable), otherwise by then the form should have submitted and the server is busy chewing on post data. Something like:

```
$("#submit_button").prop('disabled', true)
setTimeout(() => {
    $("#submit_button").prop('disabled', false)
}, 2000)
```

***Edit:*** I have been informed that by disabling the button, it's disabling the ability to do the html5 validation. So how does one stop users clicking the button multiple times without disabling it?

Comment: so what exactly you want ?

Comment: If the submit button is disabled, how are they getting validation errors?

Comment: When you click 'Add Staff' the button becomes disabled temporarily, but the form really should run HTML validation on the fields. Which it isn't

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah I see the issue. Hiding the button works, but that's not really best practice. So happy for suggestions :-)

Comment: I don't understand why you want validation if the form has already been submitted.

Comment: It's not that I want the validation when it's been submitted, I just needed to find a way for the lovely warehouse staff to not be able to keep clicking. But the disable method I was using initially also prevented the validation when the form was incorrectly filled in before submission :-)

Comment: Maybe you can replace the button text for a loading spinner and mute the colors, so the user knows they're not supposed to keep clicking? This way you don't have to hide/disable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was alluded to by @Raqha above, but the code was slightly off. Indeed temporarily turning off the pointer was the way to go. Thanks!

So this code:

```
$('#submit_button').click(e => {
    $("#submit_button").addClass('disabled')
    console.log($('#' + e.target.id).parent('form').children('input'))
    setTimeout(() => {
        $("#submit_button").removeClass('disabled')
        console.log('UN-DISABLED')
    }, 2000)
})
```

With this CSS:

```
button.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

button.enabled {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Obviously you can change the button text or add a spinner as necessary while disabled to suggest submitting if desired. Thanks internet peeps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disableing the button, you could turn off the pointer events:

`$("#submit_button").style.pointerEvents = "none";`

or better, add a class to the button, which change the color, so it looks disabled (put an opacity on it) and add the pointerEvents property.

```
#submit_button.disabled{
  opacity:.5;
  pointerEvents:none;
}
```